# doctrine2 loads one-to-many associations with fetch mode eager using too many SQL queries

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am loading a list of many entities.
These entities have a one-to-many association to other entities.
I want to load all these other entities in one single SQL query (instead of one query for every entity in the first list).

As discribed in the doctrine2 documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql this should be possible with "EAGER" loading.

but it does not work as described.

my code:

```
class User{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user", indexBy="id", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $addresses;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class Address{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;
}

class UserRepository{
    public function findUsersWithAddresses(){
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u ORDER BY u.name ASC')
            ->setFetchMode('MyBundle\Entity\User', 'addresses', \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER)
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

The method UserRepository::findUsersWithAddresses() executes 11 SQL Queries.

**How can I tell Doctrine to use only one SQL Query to load the address entities?**

I am using:

- symfony v2.0.9
- doctrine-common 2.1.4
- doctrine-dbal 2.1.5
- doctrine 2.1.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current version of doctrine doesn't support this.

There is a [feature request](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1149) about this in the doctrine2 issue tracker.

So I hope it will be implemented soon.

Comment: What was 'current version' at time of writing this answer...? I think it should be possible to do this right now right? With a `LEFT JOIN` on addresses in your DQL.

Comment: This has now been implemented in Doctrine 2.5

Answer (score 6):

According to your link:

> You can mark a **many-to-one or one-to-one** association as fetched
>   temporarily to batch fetch these entities using a WHERE .. IN query

It looks like the current version of Doctrine does not support eager loading on a *one-to-many* collection, unfortunately.

[This page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany) seems to confirm this supposition:

> ### @OneToMany
>
> Required attributes:
>
> **targetEntity**: FQCN of the referenced target entity. Can be the
>   unqualified class name if both classes are in the same namespace.
>   IMPORTANT: No leading backslash!
>
> Optional attributes:
>
> - **cascade**: Cascade Option
> - **orphanRemoval**: Boolean that specifies if
>     orphans, inverse OneToOne entities that are not connected to any
>     owning instance, should be removed by Doctrine. Defaults to false.
> - **mappedBy**: This option specifies the property name on the targetEntity
>     that is the owning side of this relation. Its a required attribute for
>     the inverse side of a relationship.

The `@OneToMany` annotation does not feature a `fetch` attribute, as opposed to `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne`.

---

## Update

I just noticed that you *can* actually eager fetch the related entities, using an explicit `LEFT JOIN` in DQL:

```
SELECT u, a FROM User u
LEFT JOIN u.addresses a
```

Do use a `LEFT JOIN`, and not an inner `JOIN`, or entities with an empty collection (`User` without any `Address`) would be omitted from the result set.

## Update (2017)

As pointed by [GusDeCool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420902/gusdecool) and [webDEVILopers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937050/webdevilopers) in the comments, the `fetch` attribute is [now supported](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany) on `@OneToMany`. The above answer is now obsolete.

Comment: I think Doctrine does support eager loading on a one-to-many collection, otherwise my method `UserRepository::findUsersWithAddresses()` would only execute 1 SQL Query instead of 11.
When i remove the `fetch="EAGER"` from the User entity and the `->setFetchMode()` from the UserRepository, my method `UserRepository::findUsersWithAddresses()` only executes 1 SQL Query

Comment: I can not use a `LEFT JOIN` for eager loading, because `->setMaxResults(10)` does not work correctly using `LEFT JOIN`s for one-to-many collections

Comment: on the latest one we can do it. doctrine 2.5. updated docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany

Comment: Indeed it works with Doctrine 2.5 and now executes one query less: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html#improve-efficiency-of-one-to-many-eager

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issues and updated my doctrine module in Zend Framework 2 to version 2.5 and now all is working fine. You can check my question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677533/doctrine2-in-zf2-dql-gives-different-result-than-findoneby-method)

Comment: Hi Wilt, can you advise on which version of doctrine ORM you are using, and which queries doctrine generates for you in that particular case? I am trying to do the same but cannot manage so far...

Comment: The TS asked about `OneToMany` not `ManyToOne` as mentioned in your linked question. Anyway eager loading seems to be supported even for `OneToMany` relations now.